# C# Проблема с кодировкой MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, кодировка

Беру текст с **немецкого** сайта в кодировке `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");`

Кладу в MySQL(5.6.31) кодировка сервера UTF-8 Unicode (utf8). Там по умолчанию определяется столбец с кодировкой latin1_swedish_ci .

После программой беру текст, и отправляю запрос(переводчику Яндекс) и получаю в ответ XML структуру, при этом я устанавливаю кодировку:

```
    private string Download(string link) // Метод получения xml структуры
    {
        downloader.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        return downloader.DownloadString(link);
    }
```

Потом, полученную структуру разбираю и перевод кладу в новый столбец, но вместо русских букв, знаки вопроса ?????

Пробовал менять кодировку столбца или перевода не помогает. Так же к подключению добавлял charset, тоже не работает. Для подключения использую коннектор Mysql `MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`

Comment: Сделайте иначе. С немецкого сайта -> Яндекс.Переводчик -> из ответа яндекса оригинал и перевод -> MySQL -> извлекаем & проверяем.

Comment: @Bulson Все равно знаки вопроса

Comment: тогда похоже дело в настройках MySQL. А если просто взять русский текст, база сохраняет нормально? И почему, кстати, установка сделана на шведский яз. ( latin1_swedish_ci .)?

Comment: @Bulson 2 столбца с 2 кодировками с utf8 и 1251, все равно знаки ???

Comment: Возможно это поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646949/converting-latin1-swedish-ci-to-utf8-with-php
Может быть вы путаете collation и charset?

Comment: @ExUser странно, но у меня заработало. utf8_general_ci для таблицы и mysql.CharacterSet = "utf8"; для коннекта

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось банальным, которое всем помогает :

Для таблицы выставить кодировку

```
utf8_general_ci
```

Для подключения к базе:

```
mysql.CharacterSet = "utf8";
```